# Run Go app as service with systemd in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: systemd, aws, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to set my Go app as a systemd service in an EC2 instance with Amazon Linux 2023 so that it restarts on crashing and system reboots.

I was following the advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45177517/5895040):

1. I created a symlink here /etc/systemd/system to /home/ec2-user/mygoapp.service with this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=My app
After=network.target

[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/path/to/binary

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Run

```
$ sudo systemctl enable mygoapp
$ sudo systemctl start mygoapp
```

But it doesn't start my app.

I also tried this mygoapp.service content:

```
[Unit]
Description=My app
ConditionPathExists=/home/ec2-user/path/to/folder/containing/go/source/files
After=network.target

[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/path/to/folder/containing/go/source/files
ExecStart=/usr/local/go/bin/go run .

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After editing mygoapp.service I run:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl stop mygoapp
$ sudo systemctl start mygoapp
```

But this doesn't work either.

What's the correct way to make this work?

Comment: If instead of a symlink you actually copy your unit file to `/etc/systemd/system`, does that change the behavior at all? What do you see in the system journal when you run `systemctl start mygoapp`?

Comment: @larsks the system journal has something like this every 3 seconds:
`... systemd[1]: mygoapp.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 9>
... systemd[1]: Stopped mygoapp.service - My app.
... systemd[1]: Started mygoapp.service - My app.
... web[121319]: 2024/01/30 23:36:16 Error loading .env file
... systemd[1]: mygoapp.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAI>
... systemd[1]: mygoapp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.`
I don't know why it fails loading .env. It doesn't happen when I run the app as
$ ./web

Comment: Your working directory is not the same. It's not going to find `./.env` because it's not starting from the same directory. You could explicitly set `WorkingDirectory` in your unit file, or you could set an `EnvironmentFile` in your unit file.

Comment: Thanks @larsks! Setting `WorkingDirectory` worked!